# Android Native Activity and Graphical Environment

Tags: java, android, c++, android-activity, android-ndk

I am trying to get deeper into android internals, I know how to use NDK, maybe even how it works, but I have question about Native Activity and other native parts provided by NDK.
As far as I know Android Desktop Environment (graphical envirnoment) is written and running in Java. This is the part of Android Framework(blue color on well-known diagramm).
If so, when running C/C++ code from android app we are running it on the linux level, behind the java, dalvik and all high level stuff.
My question is how can we have NativeActivity, to create it (draw with opengl) is one thing, but where is it in android system architecture is it still running somehow inside dalvik process instance.
The main thing I am interested in is how communication with simple (java) activities is done.
Please help to understand , maybe someone can provie a sort of diagramm to get better understanding of this.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when running C/C++ code from android app, you aren't running it "behind the java, dalvik and all high level stuff". It's executed by the Android Runtime or Dalvik.

The native activity make java calls to the Android framwork, using the JNI (Java Native Interface), in order to create its Activity.

Comment: So this means that, I am calling natively compiled object executable file for specific platform, but it in turn again call java ? So it can looks like a loop ?

Comment: You may see it as a loop. the DVM/ART calls a native implementation inside a natively compiled object library, that do calls to the DVM/ART to access Java APIs.

Comment: So in this case it cannot bring any pros using NativeActivity, because it still uses Java implementation, and you have to spent more time for calling from native layer to the Java Layer. And it will more time in copmarision of using java Activity implementation ? Am I right ?

Comment: Once it's loaded, there aren't a lot of calls from native to Java, so it's still worth it. If you don't need to do Java calls yourself every frames, you should go for it.